# Redux for route protecting in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, state

I have been trying to separate my state management in my react native application, and trying to protect my routes with authentication:

My Redux Store is composed with two reducers and a combined states:

reducers.js:

```
...
const reducers = combineReducers({
    auth:authReducer,
    position: positionReducer,
})

export default reducers;
```

AuthReducer.js :

```
import * as Types from '../actions/types';

export const defaultState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        phoneNumber: null,
        uid: null,
        photoURL: null
    },
    authError: ''
}

module.exports = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Types.LOGIN_SUCCESS: {
            var userObj = {
                username: null,
                uid: action.response.user.uid,
                email: action.response.user.email,
                phoneNumber: null,
                photoURL: null,
            }
        }
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: '',
                user: userObj,
                isAuthenticated: true,
            }
        case Types.LOGIN_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: action.error.message,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            };
        case Types.SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: {
                    uid: action.response.user.uid,
                    email: action.response.user.email
                }
            }
        case Types.SIGN_IN_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                authError: action.error.message
            }
        case Types.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
            }
        case Types.LOGOUT_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Store.js :

```
import { createStore, compose,applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from '../reducers';
import authState from '../reducers/authReducer';
import positionState from '../reducers/positionReducer';
defaultState = {
    auth: authState,
    position: positionState
}

export const configureStore = (initialState = defaultState , action) => {
    var store = createStore(
        reducers, 
        initialState, 
        compose(autoRehydrate(), applyMiddleware(thunk)));
        //AsyncStorage.clear();
        persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage });

    return store;
}
```

My navigation.js is like so:

```
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: LoadingStack,
    App: MainStack,
    Auth: authStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

in AuthLoading.js while logging the variable state.auth.isAuthenticated, I get undefined as a result, I am using Reactotron for inspecting, I am getting:

```
auth: fn(),
position: fn(),
```